# how to set image in more view controller's navigation bar and also change the colour of more label from white to green..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.6

I try to set image on navigation bar. when we pressed more button in tabbar..The default colour is blue.i wanna set image and chnge the colour of more label from white to green..Please help me

My code is given below, but it does not work

Appdelegte.m

```
tabMenu.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[Uiimage imagewithnamed :@"nav.png"]];

tabMenu.moreNavigationController.delegate =self;
tabMenu.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
[[[self.tabBarController moreNavigationController] navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

However You can get instance of this **"More"** `ViewController` using...

```
UIViewController *moreViewController = tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController;
```

`moreViewController.view` property contains `UITableView` and we can use it. 
For example : To Add `tableHeaderView` :

```
UITableView *moreTableView = (UITableView*)moreViewController.view;
moreTableView.tableHeaderView = myOwnCustomView;
```

For more Reference you can check this Thread on Apple : [moreNavigationController](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2399024?threadID=2399024&tstart=0)